# import pygame fails with embedded c++

Tags: python, c++, dll, pygame, mingw32

Hi guys this is the problem

I have installed python 2.7 and pygame 1.9 in a windows 7 32 bin
When I use pygame with the python interpeter there is no problem it works fine

Then for the line

```
import pygame
```

no problem with console or calling python and the filename

But I want to embed this in a c++ project compiled with mingw32. When I import other packages like cv2 or numpy no problem but in the case of pygame I have this error

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Does anybody knows where is the problem?

A lot of thanks

Comment: I have solved after a lot of googling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved after a lot of googling. The problem was with the pygame packages in msi format.

I uninstalled it and I have installed wheel and the package

```
pygame‑1.9.2a0‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl
```

from the page http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

And that works for me. There was a problem with some dll missing in the case of msi packages and minggw32 compiling

A lot of thanks to all of us

:)

Comment: sorry I have copied the wrong name of the package it was

Comment: pygame‑1.9.2a0‑cp27‑none‑win32.whl